# what is the use of `attr :str` in this code

Tags: ruby

here the code shows `attr :str`. what is the use of it and how this code works?

```
  class SizeMatters
    include Comparable
    attr :str

    def <=>(anOther)
      str.size <=> anOther.str.size
    end

    def initialize(str)
      @str = str
    end

    def inspect
      @str
    end

  end
```

cant understand the use of `attr` in the line 3. even i know about `attr_accessor`.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could describe precisely, what, *exactly* is unclear to you about the documentation of `Module#attr`, so that the Ruby developers can improve the documentation. That way, other people don't run into the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`attr_accessor :str` defines 2 methods on the class: `str` and `str=`.  `attr :str` only defines one: `str`. `attr` and `attr_reader` are the same thing .

Comment: `'cat'.between?('ant', 'dog')` is returning `true` but `'gnu'.between?('ant', 'dog') ` is returning 'false'. why it is?

Comment: and in the above code i defined a `comparable` mixin then why it is need of defining method `def <=>(anOther)`.  @steenslag

Comment: @amarjeetsingh Those are completely different questions. The string 'cat' is alphabetically between 'ant' and 'dog', and the <=> method of String is built to compare alphabetically.  A SizeMatters instance is built to compare by string size (by it's <=> method).

Answer (score 3):

**This is the list of accessors in Ruby:**

```
attr_reader :var
# has the effect of:
def var
  @var
end
```

---

```
attr_writer :var
# has the effect of:
def var=(value)
  @var = value
end
```

---

```
attr_accessor :var
# has the effect of:
attr_reader :var
attr_writer :var
```

---

`attr` works as `attr_reader` in the form used in your code: `attr :str`.

Here is an example of use in an instance of the class:

```
sm = SizeMatters.new('hello')
sm.str #=> "hello"
sm.str = 'hi' #=> undefined method `str=' for hello:SizeMatters
```

It is not possible to change the instance variable (attr) `@str` for the instance of `SizeMatters`

---

If used as `attr: :str, true` works as `attr_accessor`, but is **deprecated**.

---

For reference check here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-attr